# Template for modal from remote page

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am implementing modals as an ember component and I was wondering if and how could this be accomplished: If the content of the modal is coming from a different page, how would it be rendered as a template:

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/NUCgp/918/
The script above opens a modal with this content:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/

But what if I wanted some extra data that depends on specific users, coming from the routes model? How would I insert something like

```
 {{#each link in links}} 
   {{#link-to 'link.url'}}{{link.title}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

into the remote page, so it would be rendered as a template, and not regular text?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very quick and easy example just to give you a right direction. You can play with it and parse the html to extract content (which is not relevant to the question).

You can setup a component for modal element. I've setup a component property (attribute) `contentURL` where you can set the url of the content.

### Component handlebars

Notice the `{{content}}` which we used later in the action to save the ajax result. Action `showModal` is added on the link to execute the ajax call.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/bootstrap-modal">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" {{action "showModal"}}>Click me !</a>
    <!-- Modal -->

     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">{{content}}</div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <!-- /.modal-content -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal -->
</script>
```

### Component JS

```
App.BootstrapModalComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    /*initModal: function(){

    }.on('didInsertElement'),*/
    contentURL: null,
    content: 'Content is loading...',
    actions: {
        showModal: function(){
            var self = this;
            var contentURL = this.get('contentURL');

            if(contentURL == null){
                this.set('content', '<p>No content url is given</p>');
            }

            console.log('get content from url > ' + contentURL);
            $.ajax({
              url: contentURL,
              dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function(){console.log('before send');},
                error: function(xhr, status, message){
                    console.log(message);
                },
                success: function (content) {
                    // parse and get the right html for the content
                    self.set('content', content);
              }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Now you can call the component `bootstrap-modal` on your template like `{{bootstrap-modal}}`

### For example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{bootstrap-modal contentURL="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/"}}
</script>
```

jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/sisir/NUCgp/1713/